# Trouble getting MySQL to find a user who is active in one year but not in subsequent year

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_data (
  userid int(11) NOT NULL,
  computer varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  logondate date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Which is a large table with around 400 unique users and 20 computers, and around 20,000 entries from 5 years of users logging onto the computers.

I want to create a summary table that will list off the number of unique users per year per specific computer, in addition to how many of those users are new (i.e., no previous instances of logging on to any computer before that year, in addition to users who have no further instances of logging on to any computer in the future:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS summary_computer_use (
  computer varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  year_used date NOT NULL,
  number_of_users int(11) NOT NULL,
  number_of_new_users int(11) NOT NULL,
  number_of_terminated_users int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT into summary_computer_use (computer, year_used)
    select computer, distinct year(logondate) from users_data;
```

I can get the unique users per year:

```
UPDATE summary_computer_use as a 
inner join (
    select computer, year(logondate) as year_used,
        count(distinct userid) as number_of_users
    from users_data
    group by computer, year(logondate)
) as b on a.computer = b.computer and 
a.year_used = b.year_used
set a.number_of_users = b.number_of_users;
```

But I am stumped as to how to write a select statement that will find the number of users in a given year that are using a computer for the first time (no logon dates that occur earlier than that given year) or who never logon again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 20,000 entries is not at all a large data set in the RDBMS arena.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you're after:

```
select y, count(userid) as newusers from
(
    select userid, min(year(logondate)) as y from users_data group by userid
) tmp
group by y;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just managed to debug the select statement so that it actually works (my actual tables, and the select statement is more complex than the way I described it in the post, so I had to modify your select to work without errors). It is not working exactly the way it should, but that could be because I did something wrong. I'll play with it with some test data, when I have some time over the weekend, and see if I can get it working properly, and I'll let you know in a couple days.

Comment: You'll need to group by userid and by computer, IIUC.  Also, `MIN(YEAR(logondate))` should be `YEAR(MIN(logondate))` to take advantage of the presumed index on `logondate`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this produces the summary you want:

```
   SELECT computers.computer,
          timespan.yyyy                 AS "year_used",
          COALESCE(allusers.num, 0)     AS "number_of_users",
          COALESCE(newusers.num, 0)     AS "number_of_new_users",
          COALESCE(terminations.num, 0) AS "number_of_terminated_users"
     FROM (SELECT DISTINCT computer
             FROM users_data) computers
     JOIN (SELECT (2000+i) AS yyyy
             FROM integers
            WHERE i BETWEEN 0 AND 10) timespan
LEFT JOIN (  SELECT YEAR(logondate) AS logonyear,
                   computer,
                   COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS "num"
              FROM users_data
          GROUP BY 1, 2) allusers
       ON timespan.yyyy = allusers.logonyear AND computers.computer = allusers.computer
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT last_logon AS logonyear,
                   computer,
                   COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS "num"
              FROM (  SELECT computer,
                             userid,
                             YEAR(MAX(logondate)) AS "last_logon"
                        FROM users_data
                    GROUP BY 1, 2) last_user_logons
           GROUP BY 1, 2) terminations
       ON timespan.yyyy = terminations.logonyear AND computers.computer = terminations.computer
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT first_logon AS logonyear,
                   computer,
                   COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS "num"
              FROM (  SELECT computer,
                             userid,
                             YEAR(MIN(logondate)) AS "first_logon"
                        FROM users_data
                    GROUP BY 1, 2) first_user_logons
           GROUP BY 1, 2) newusers
       ON timespan.yyyy = newusers.logonyear AND computers.computer = newusers.computer;
```

Those various subqueries represent:

- The set of distinct `computers`
- The `timespan` of years we are interested in

  - Note:  using an [integers table](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/07/the-integers-table/)
  - Note:  We exclude yesteryear (2011, at the time of this writing), since we can't "close the books" on last year's terminations until the present year is complete.
- The number of distinct users by computer by year (`allusers`)
- The number of `newusers` by computer by year
  (Built atop all `first_logon` records for a user on a computer)
- The number of `terminations` by computer by year
  (Built atop all `last_logon` records)